# Print centered String inside hollow rectangle Java

Tags: java

I am working on a java program in which I am trying to utilize a header made of asterisks.

I would like to output a message in the center of the header but am not completely sure how to go about doing this.

```
static void header(String msg) {
    int h = 3;
    int w = 60;  

    for(int j = 1; j <= h; j++)
    {  
        for(int i = 1; i <= w; i++)
        {
            if(j == 1 || j == h || i == 1 || i == w)  
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
}
```

So this header will print an asterisk, hollow rectangle 60 wide and 3 tall. I would like to format this as a custom method so I can reference this easily throughout the program. As you can see I have formatted the frame, so the issue is getting the string in there and centering it inside the frame. I sort of have an idea that I need to use msg.length() and possibly a printf() to do this but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: What's the specific issue? You know how big the rectangle is. You know how long the string is. The rest seems like math, no?

Comment: What if the string is greater than 60 characters, which is your hard coded width?

Comment: Dave the specific issue is I have only a vague idea of how to insert the string inside this frame. The string will be a variable length as msg will be denoted each time the method is used. 60 is simply the width I have chosen for this particular heading, I can change it at will by modifying the variable w so this is not an issue.

Comment: So,  you know how tall it is (e.g., which line the header text will be on). You know how many spaces before and after the header text you'll need. You know the header text...

Comment: No, the only thing I "know" is which line the text will be on (row 2). Msg will be initialized by the user each time the method is called. So in one call Msg  may be as short as "Hello!" in another it could be "Hello! My name is Johnathon!" or longer. So I do not know how long the header text will be or how many spaces before and after since I want to center this text in the frame and depending on what the user inputs the space before and after will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the box first, you might want to print the top, the text and the bottom. To print the text (the center rows) you can use this

```
    if (msg.length() > (w-2)) {
        msg = msg.substring(1, w-2);
    }
    int space=(w-2-msg.length())/2;
    System.out.printf("%s%" + (space + msg.length()) + "s%" + (w - (space + msg.length())) + "s", "*", msg, "*");
```

Comment: This works for what I am trying to achieve, thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
private void printMessage(final String message) {

    String[] lines = message.split("\\r?\\n");

    int maxWidth = Arrays.stream(lines).mapToInt(String::length).max().getAsInt();

    System.out.println(repeatString("*", maxWidth + 2));

    for(final String line : lines) {
        int lengthDiff = maxWidth - line.length();
        System.out.print("*" + repeatString(" ", (lengthDiff / 2)) + line + repeatString(" ", (lengthDiff / 2)) + "*\n");
    }

    System.out.println(repeatString("*", maxWidth + 2));
}

private String repeatString(final String string, final int repetitions) {
    return new String(new char[repetitions]).replace("\0", string);
}
```

Testing:

```
String message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\n" +
                 "Suspendisse volutpat lobortis sem at gravida. Aenean aliquet erat justo,\n" +
                 "id ultricies mi ullamcorper eu. Mauris scelerisque accumsan metus vitae congue. Vestibulum\n";

printMessage(message);
```

Output:

```
********************************************************************************************
*                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.                 *
*         Suspendisse volutpat lobortis sem at gravida. Aenean aliquet erat justo,         *
*id ultricies mi ullamcorper eu. Mauris scelerisque accumsan metus vitae congue. Vestibulum*
********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Is there not a simpler way to do this? I dont care about multiple lines or adjusting the width to fit the message. I just want to be able to center a simple string such as "Hello!" inside of the frame I have defined. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Using what you've provided, you can construct your header by considering the amount of padding you will need in order to center your text. When you've reached this amount you will be at approximately the center of the header, then you can start printing characters from your message

---

This solution will only print on the middle row, based on your comment:

> "No, the only thing I "know" is which line the text will be on (row
>   2)"

But hopefully the below changes can help you arrive at a final solution

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        header("Test Message");
        header("This message has more than sixty characters causing the header to grow");
    }

    static void header(String msg) {
        int headerHeight = 3;
        int headerWidth = msg.length() > 60 ? msg.length() + 60 : 60;
        int paddingRequired = (headerWidth - msg.length() - 2) / 2;
        paddingRequired++; //To account for the boundary asterisk

        for(int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= headerHeight; rowIndex++) {
            for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= headerWidth; columnIndex++) {
                //Is this one of the asterisks at the edges of the middle row
                boolean isBoundaryAsterisk = (columnIndex == 1 || columnIndex == headerWidth);
                if((rowIndex == headerHeight) || (rowIndex == 1) || isBoundaryAsterisk) {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                else if((columnIndex > paddingRequired) && ((columnIndex - paddingRequired - 1) < msg.length())) {
                    System.out.print(msg.charAt(columnIndex-paddingRequired - 1));
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

---

Example output:

```
************************************************************
*                       Test Message                       *
************************************************************
**********************************************************************************************************************************
*                             This message has more than sixty characters causing the header to grow                             *
**********************************************************************************************************************************
```

Note that the second example is greater than your initial 60, but the width of the header will grow to ensure spaces will be included